# Getting unexpcted results in perl dynamic qw array

Tags: arrays, perl

I am looping over a query and I am trying to create a dynamic qw array.

```
my $f_name_string = '';
while($sth->fetch)
{
    $f_name_string.=$fname.=" "
}
$sth->finish();
my @FNAME_ORDER = (qw('$f_name_string'));
```

`print("@SENSOR_ORDER");` prints `'$f_name_string'`

Comment: `qw` is not intended to be dynamic. Maybe you want to split on spaces? Just use [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qw` doesn't interpolate. And I don't know why you're adding spaces to `$fname` by using `$fname .= ' '` instead of `$fname . ' '`.

```
while ($sth->fetch)
{
    $f_name_string .= $fname . ' ';
}
```

makes more sense, but even more sense is to not create a string in the first place:

```
my @FNAME_ORDER; # why all uppercase anyway?
while ($sth->fetch)
{
    push @FNAME_ORDER, $fname;
}
$sth->finish();
```

This makes more sense. If you want to print it out or later create a string separated by spaces, it's easy to do, easier than separating on spaces (in case any `$fname` could have a space in it).

Answer (score 3):

```
qw( foo bar )
```

is short for

```
split ' ', q( foo bar )    # q() = Single quotes, doesn't interpolate.
```

so you could use

```
my @fname_order = split ' ', $f_name_string;
```

but it would make more sense to just populate the array directly.

```
my @fname_order;
while($sth->fetch) {
    push @fname_order, $fname;
}
```